# Is it possible to super scale a dockerised selenium grid?

Tags: docker, selenium-grid2

I am currently developing a dockerised selenium grid to run around 800 functional tests ( [see my post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/article/building-scalable-dockerized-testing-grid-reporting-demiris) ) and I was hoping I could launch up to 800 nodes with one hub in a single grid [inside a BIG aws instance]. The idea would be to run all my tests at the same time and finish in [let's say] 10 minutes.

As I understand [from this post](http://biercoff.com/docker-selenium-grid-optimal-configuration/) that is not possible.

I launched 20 nodes and my tests are only populating the 10. That is only 10 firefox instances.

Are there restrictions built in the selenium server or the hub's docker image?

I was hoping that the ease of scaling dockerised services would take the selenium grid capabilities to a whole new level...

Is the dockerised implementation of selenium grid 'stuck' to 10 nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run as many concurrent tests as the system can maintain. Without knowing anything about your current platform I have no idea what is limiting to just 10 nodes. In my current stack my test runner has a max fork property that limits the number of concurrent tests. You might want to look into what your test runner has set as the max number of concurrent tests. I know of no limit for selenium grid for tests it would be silly to limit it at 10.